# Searching Tables Based on TextField Input

Tags: sql, authentication, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have started by creating a mobile application and adding all the main functionality. Now I would like a user to be able to access their personal information from the a table called "Users" based on a login page. I started by creating a blank page and filling it with two text fields which represent a username and password. The username is the user's unique reference number and password is their date of birth.

When the page is submitted, I want the values in the text fields to be matched with the reference number and date of birth in the database table and return all the results specific to that user on a separate page. I need to use SQL code for this and I have tried looking into dynamic actions but I can't get my head around retrieving the values from the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

The values from the text fields need to be submitted.  If you create a process and set it to the processing point then the values will be submitted by the time your processes execute.  One way way to retrieve a submitted apex item's value would be to use the colon, if your item is call *P1_USERNAME* then to retrieve the value you can use ***:P1_USERNAME*** in any PL/SQL or ***&P1_USERNAME.*** to retrieve the text value of your item.